# Running cURL in Brackets

Tags: php, curl, web, adobe-brackets

In the Brackets IDE I'm running PHP functions that need the cURL Library enabled. since the IDE manages in some way to run these files with Live Preview it may have some kind of support over it. How can I install/enable the cURL Library in Live Preview?

Comment: No. The IDE is not a server and would not be able to execute cURL requests on it's own for you, period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live Preview has two modes of operation:

- Run using a simple backend supplied by Brackets, which just statically serves up the files -- this is the default
- Run using your own backend (which could be PHP, Node, ASP -- anything)

Using your own backend is the most flexible, but it disables some Live Preview functionality. Notably, only CSS files update as you type -- everything else will update only on save (classic "live reload"). Check out the [Live Preview documentation](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#live-preview) for details.